# F# HttpClientHandler Dispose

Tags: f#, httpclient

While it's generally advised not to create an instance of HttpClient for each request, there might be exceptions, like when an instance is conditionally created based on whether a proxy should be used. The following snippet illustrates this, but it doesn't provide an opportunity for HttpClientHandler to be disposed. So, what is the correct approach to handle this?

```ml
use httpClient =
    if System.String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace apiHttpProxy |> not then
        let httpClientHandler =
            new HttpClientHandler(Proxy = WebProxy(System.Uri(apiHttpProxy), true))

        new HttpClient(httpClientHandler, true)
    else
        new HttpClient()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HttpClient has constructor, which has boolean argument specifying, whether handler should be automatically disposed on client dispose. [see details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-net-http-httpclient-ctor(system-net-http-httpmessagehandler-system-boolean))

And I see you already have it in your example, so you don‘t need to do anything else.